# Multiindiex str replacement on column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to replace all values in a column in a multi index dataframe, I found a dirty way to do it, but I am looking for something cleaner

The data is imported from a .xlsx if that helps at all as it had the ability to remove "," from the first column using the thousands operator.

all numbers are strings so I need to convert them to floats or ints hence the str.replace function

Example dataframe

```
Name    0                       1                      ...
Col     A           B           A            B         ...
0       409511  30.3%           355529   30.3%  ...
1       332276  20.3%           083684   20.3%  ...
2       138159  10.3%           570834   10.3%  ...
```

If I use

```
df['0','B']= df['0','B'].str.replace('%','').astype(float)
```

This works, but I don't want to have to do that for every single column

I have been trying to play around with

df.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'B']].str.replace('%','').astype(float)

but am getting the error

'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'

I tried with

df.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'Percent']].replace('%','')

Which returns the dataframe without error but does nothing to it

If I do

df.loc[:,pd.IndexSlice[:,'Percent']].replace('%','').astype(float)

could not convert string to float: '33.3%'

I read through https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html but there is nothing on replace

I have also been unable to find anything in this 
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.05-hierarchical-indexing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `Index.Slice` and `loc`, and `update` (*Note*: *you need `regex=True`*)

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.update(df.loc[:, idx[:,'B']].replace('%', '', regex=True).astype(float))

Out[1374]:
        0             1
        A     B       A     B
0  409511  30.3  355529  30.3
1  332276  20.3   83684  20.3
2  138159  10.3  570834  10.3
```

---

Or Using `filter` and `update` back to `df`

```
df.update(df.filter(like='B').replace('%', '', regex=True).astype(float))

Out[1363]:
        0             1
        A     B       A     B
0  409511  30.3  355529  30.3
1  332276  20.3   83684  20.3
2  138159  10.3  570834  10.3
```

---

Comment: Thank you, this has worked perfectly, I will read into what regex=True and df.update does exactly